# Expected norm $1$ of inner product

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, probability-distributions, normed-spaces

Let $A$ denote a random vector with elements sampled i.i.d according to a distribution with mean $0$ and variance $\sigma^2$ and $x$ be a fixed vector. Can we calculate $E[||A^T x||_1 ]$ exactly or lower bound it somehow? 
I am specifically interested in a discrete distribution in the following form.
$$
\begin{cases} 0,    &w.p. &1-2p  \\ 1, &w.p. &p \\ -1,   &w.p. &p \end{cases}
$$

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I have tried to find a recursive connection. For a 1 dimensional vector, the answer is $(1-2p)|x|$. But I have not been able to get anything for higher dimensional vectors

Comment: $A$ and $x$ are both vectors?  So then $A^T x$ is a scalar, and $||A^T x||_1 = |A^T x|$?

Answer (score 1):

**Upper-bound.**
Let the shape of your random matrix $A$ be $n\times m$. First observe that $E[\|Ax\|_1] \le E[\sqrt{m}\|Ax\|_2] \le \left(mE\|Ax\|_2^2\right)^{1/2}$, where the second inequality is Jensen's inequality.

Now, let $\Sigma=\sigma^2 I_{m \times m}$ be the common covariance matrix of the rows of $A$ and $\mu = O_m$ be the mean. Then
$$
E\|Ax\|_2^2 = \sum_{i=1}^nE|a_i^Tx|^2 = n(trace(xx^T\Sigma) + \mu^T\Sigma\mu) = n\sigma^2\|x\|^2_2.
$$
Therefore,
$$
E\|Ax\|_1 \le \sqrt{nm}\sigma\|x\|_2.
$$

## Edit: non-trivial lower-bound

Let $s \in \{-1,0,+1\}^m$ be the vector of the signs of the coordinates of $x$, and let $\|x\|_0 = \|s\|_0$ be the number of nonzero coordinates of $x$. Also, let $b = a_1 \in \mathbb R^m$ be the first row of the random matrix $A$. Then, one computes

$$
\begin{split}
E|a_1^Tx| = E|\sum_j x_jb_j| &= \sum_{z \in \{-1,0,+1\}^m}\left|\sum_{j=1}^m x_jz_j\right|P(b_1=z_1,\ldots,b_m=z_m)\\
&= \sum_{z \in \{-1,0,+1\}^m}\left|\sum_{j=1}^m x_jz_j\right|\Pi_{j=1}^mP(Z_j=z_j)\\
&= \sum_{z \in \{-1,0,+1\}^m}\left|\sum_{j=1}^m x_jz_j\right|p^{\|z\|_0}(1-2p)^{m-\|z\|_0}\\
&=\sum_{z \in \{-1,0,+1\}^m}p^{\|z\|_0}(1-2p)^{m-\|z\|_0}\left|\sum_{j=1}^m x_jz_j\right|\\
& \ge 2p^{\|s\|_0}(1-2p)^{m-\|s\|_0}\left|\pm \sum_{j=1}^m x_js_j\right|\\
&= 2p^{\|x\|_0}(1-2p)^{m-\|x\|_0} \|x\|_1,
\end{split}
$$

> where the inequality is because we have focused only on those $z \in \{-1,0,+1\}^m$ which have the same (or opposite) signs as $x$.

Therefore, we have the lower-bound
$$
E\|Ax\|_1 \ge 2np^{\|x\|_0}(1-2p)^{m-\|x\|_0}\|x\|_1.
$$

In fact, be restricted to those $z \in \{-1,0,+1\}$ whose coordinates have signs match those of $x$ or are simply zeroeth-out, we get the better bound

$$
E\|Ax\|_1 \ge 2n\sum_{I \subseteq supp(x)}p^{|I|}(1-2p)^{m-|I|}\|x_I\|_1 \ge 2np^{\|x\|_0}(1-2p)^{m-\|x\|_0}\|x\|_1,
$$
where $supp(x) := \{j \in \{1,\ldots,m\} \mid x_j \ne 0\}$ is the support of $x$, and $x_I \in \mathbb R^{|I|}$ is the restriction of the vector $x$ onto the indices in the subset $I$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, the last expression in the lower bound part is basically zero. Do you think we could derive a non-trivial lower bound on the expectation?

Comment: Yes, i just realized that too :). I'm working on a nontrivial bound. I'll post a skeleton here in a moment.

Comment: Added a lower-bound, namely $E\|Ax\|_1 \ge 2np^{\|x\|_0}(1-2p)^{m-\|x\|_0}\|x|_1$.

Comment: Thanks for the effort. It seems that we can find a much tighter lower bound. I managed to show to that $\frac{2np}{2p(m-1)+1}$ lower bounds the expected norm.

Comment: (1) Your bound is not possible (as it completely regardless of $x$). What happens to your proposed lower bound when $x = 0$ ?
(2) MathX is a collaborative plateform. Asking a question, and having others invest time on it, and returning to say, "btw, I solved my problem in secret using a magic trick; thx anyways!" doesn't seem quite right. Consider adding your updates (including tentative self-answers) under your question as an edit.

Comment: Sorry about the typo. I meant $\frac{2p}{2p(m-1)+1}||x||_1$. I also agree about posting my solution. I will edit my question as soon as possible.

Comment: OK, interestng. Modulo constant, we have the same bound then, namely $E\|Ax\|_1 = \Omega(\|x\|_1)$. The exception is when $p$ is close $1/2$, as my bound degenerates to $0$....